# What is the kind of baidu map for android

Tags: android

I want to know if the baidu lacate is the same as gps locate or wifi locate ,and what the different about  gps locate and baidu locate.

Answer (score 0):

I was posted to china to work since a few month back. And I had tried out the baidu map API for Android (switching from the original Google map API). The main reason behind it is the location.

Using the default find current location in google doesn't show the correct position of where i am on the map. There is a different between the latitude and longitude for google and baidu. Baidu map will show a more accurate for current location. On top of that, I had also found website that shows the difference from the latitude and longitude to the correct ones. (But I found it quite troublesome)

For example, [in this document](http://www.doc88.com/p-908538504653.html) (Hopefully You can understand Chinese, if not i can do some translation for you ;) )

If latitude and longitude reading are from the GPS (as you know Android is the mobile version of Google), you will need to do a conversion.

I had tested out on samsumg galaxy S2 as well as HTC T528. Both of the phone do show the differences in their latitude and longitude.

Hopefully this will help.